# Looking for a Github-style private message system in Django

Tags: django, messagebox

I've looked at various django private message systems but haven't seen anything that has implemented github-style message.

On gitHub, when someone sends you a message, you receive the full message by email.
You can reply directly to the email (to a tokenized email adress, unique to the sender-recipient-thread trio), so it keeps both sender and recipient email address hidden, track/copy all exchange in the GitHub site inbox and doesn't require recipient or sender to visit GitHub to reply.

That's great UX and I was curious to know if someone had implemented it in Django.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A reusable app for this will be great :)

The problem here is that the implementation is not a pure django solution, and must be integrated with a mail server and cron jobs.

I know jutdahelpdesk can create tickets from mail messages https://github.com/justquick/jutdahelpdesk

Check the 5. Initial Configuration section in the readme file.

Also, something like Lamson (http://lamsonproject.org/) could be added to the mix to make it more pythonic.

If you go ahead creating this kind of app get in touch with me :)

Comment: Hey @philgo20 did you end up implementing this? I wanted to do something similar too.

Comment: No but I am pretty sure that by now it's findable. Good luck.